# How to print out data from sqlite3 database?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

def function():
with sqlite3.connect("test.db")as db:
    c = db.cursor()

index = 1
while index == 1:

    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(name,age);")
    insert = "INSERT INTO data(name,age) VALUES ('JOHN',16)"
    c.execute(insert)
    db.commit()
    index += 1
    display()

def display():
with sqlite3.connect("test.db")as db:
    c = db.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS test_VIEW AS SELECT name, age FROM data")
db.commit()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM test_VIEW")

function = function()
output = display()
```

Referencing to [SQLite Views](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_views.htm). I'm trying to print out all my data from database. But from the sample code above, I only get a blank output. How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to loop through the results. See full mockup below. I have modified it so it can print out nicely using `pandas` dataframe.:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

def function():
    with sqlite3.connect("test.db")as db:
        c = db.cursor()
        index = 1
        while index == 1:

            c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(name,age);")
            insert = "INSERT INTO data(name,age) VALUES ('JOHN',16)"
            c.execute(insert)
            db.commit()
            index += 1
            display()

def display():
    with sqlite3.connect("test.db")as db:
        c = db.cursor()
        c.execute("CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS test_VIEW AS SELECT name, age FROM data")
        db.commit()  
        data_pd = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM test_VIEW',db)
        print data_pd


function = function()
output = display()
```

result below:

```
   name  age
0  JOHN   16
```

Comment: Oh, it works now. Is there any way to print it out like (in a form of table) below?

Name    Age
--------    -----
John      16

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use `fetchall()` method

In the display funtion do

```
query = c.execute("SELECT * FROM test_VIEW")
data = c.fetchall()
for d in data:
    print (d)
```